# Crash in didReceiveRemoteNotification

Tags: ios, swift

Crash is happening on live app. I can't obtain crash log. I can see following in Organizer->Crashes, clicking on it takes me to following line as mentioned below. How do I debug this crash or prevent it?

[Crash in Organizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joxvJ.png)

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    // Crash happens here
    let tabBar:UITabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you just checking `rootViewController` is `UITabBarController`. But i think, crash happens because you don't call `completionHandler`. Try to add at the end of the method:

```
completionHandler(.noData) // or with other parameters of UIBackgroundFetchResult type.
```

**From Apple documentation:**

> As soon as you finish processing the notification, you must call the block in the handler parameter or your app will be terminated. Your app has up to 30 seconds of wall-clock time to process the notification and call the specified completion handler block. In practice, you should call the handler block as soon as you are done processing the notification. The system tracks the elapsed time, power usage, and data costs for your app’s background downloads. Apps that use significant amounts of power when processing remote notifications may not always be woken up early to process future notifications.

Check apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application)

Comment: Tx will add that line. TabBarController is root of my views. In Tab Bar I've Navigation controllers and then VCs. Once I get tabBar I navigate my way into finding the correct VC where the notification should be linked to. It does work all the time except this crash in some scenario which I can't reproduce during testing. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: you should use guard

Comment: @vanya Why? `let tabBar = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController` this line of code returns optional `UITabBarController?`

Comment: @vpoltave when you work with optionals, you should used guard statement to avoid  situation when value is nil, which will crash and might be your case as well.